# Ubuntu 14.04 login loop after apt-get upgrade

Tags: 14.04, login

After `apt-get upgrade` and restarting Ubuntu 14.04, I encountered login loop problem. `.xsession-errors` revealed that `ligGL` error failed to open drm device and that permission was denied, failed to load driver i965 and that permission was denied to create file. `/cache/dconf/user and init not found`

Permission for `.Xauthority` is `- rwxrwxrwx`

Also gave execute  permission to `/usr/bin/genome-session`
`Chown` to `.Xauthority`

And tried to

`- - reinstall ubuntu-desktop     and     - - reinstall ubuntu-session`

And gave 777 permission to `$home` none of that works and problem persist. Kindly Help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Lets you edit `/home/username/.Xauthority` ?

or install Lightdm for now:

`sudo apt-get install lightdm`

After installing lightdm enter the following commands to set lightdm as the default display manager:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Accept and follow instructions.

**Reboot**